# LiveChart Y-Scrolling Step Size

Tags: c#, charts, livecharts

Does the current version of LiveChart support the following features?

1. Configuration of the size of the zooming-step.
2. Configuration which series should be zoomed and which not.

---

We currently develop an application with LiveChart and we plan to implement a Y-Zooming mechanism.
Currently we want to realize the Y-Zooming mechanism on our own with the help of the properties
`Axis::MaxValue` and `Axis::MinValue`, because there is no option to define the zooming steps of the y-value
and no option for zooming only one of the drawn `LineSeries`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! The second half of your question (what you're actually asking) looks very answerable by someone familiar with LiveChart, but the first part (the context) would be out-of-scope for this site if that were what you were all you said. I rearranged it to make it clearer to readers.

Comment: Hello jpaugh,Thank you for this optimization. Hopefully I will get an answer. The problem is, that I think it is not possible. So probably nobody will tell me, that it is not possible.